# Front wheel axle making clicking sound

Tags: axle, clicking

Recently, I realized that my bike front wheel axle is making clicking sound.
Now, i am trying to resolve the problem.

Do I need to put a grease(special oil),
 or I need to buy new front wheel axle,
or I need to change ball bearings.

I am a novice in this.

Comment: Are you sure its the axle making sounds and say, not a detensioned spoke?

Comment: I am not sure. But I didn't change tension in the spokes recently.

Comment: First you determine what's clicking.  A "twang" sound is usually a spoke.  If you decide it's the bearings, the first thing to try would be to repack the bearings (assuming it's a hub with loose balls, not a cartridge unit).

Comment: Thanks @DanielRHicks. It is a clicking sound. Oil in the hub will work?

Comment: Can you tell us what your bike is, how old, what type of hub? That will help someone can give specific advice on what can be the hub you have. A picture would be helpful too.

Comment: No, you take apart the bearings, clean them, and apply new grease.

Comment: Other possible causes - brake rub or tyre sprues hitting the frame.    Remove wheel from fork and spin the axle feeling for rough turning.

Answer (score 3):

Lift the front wheel off the pavement and spin the wheel so that it moves freely. If you are hearing a clicking sound and/or the wheel visibly slows slightly in conjunction with the sound then you may have a bearing problem. You could open it up and repack the bearings. By repacking I mean clean out the old grease and put new grease on the bearings. There should be enough grease that the bearings don't fall out of their ring if turned upside down but no more than that. Do not use oil. Grease is what to use for bearings. Close everything up and reinstall the wheel. It should be a little bit sluggish for the first few spins because the grease is getting settled into place. Should be good to go from then on.
Make sure you inspect each bearing for damage/rust. If either is found then you need to replace the bearings as well. Good luck.